# class has no constructor forward declaration

Tags: c++, sdl, state

I'm trying to create a state engine in my game for the different screens. id start screen, maybe a file chooser in the future, overworld map, menu screen, etc. But when I forward declare the class it says there are no constructors.

GameState.h:

```
#pragma once

class GameState
{
public:
    virtual ~GameState() {}
    virtual void Update() {}
    virtual void HandleEvents() {}
    virtual void Draw(Graphics& gfx) {}

    GameState* getCurrentState()
    {
        return currentState;
    }
    void ChangeState(GameState* state)
    {
        currentState = state;
    }

protected:
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    GameState* currentState;
};
```

GameStates.h

```
#pragma once
#include "GameState.h"
#include "Texture.h"
#include "Keyboard.h"

class TitleGameState;
class IntroGameState : public GameState
{
public:
    IntroGameState(SDL_Renderer* renderer, KeyboardClient& kbd)
        :
        kbd(kbd)
    {
        background = new Texture("red.png", renderer);
        this->renderer = renderer;
    }
    ~IntroGameState() {}
    void HandleEvents()
    {
        while (!kbd.KeyEmpty())
        {
            KeyEvent e = kbd.ReadKey();
            switch (e.GetCode())
            {
            case SDLK_RETURN:
                if (e.IsPress())
                {
                    currentState = new TitleGameState(renderer, kbd);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    void Logic() {}
    void Draw(Graphics& gfx)
    {
        background->Draw(0, 0, gfx);
    }

private:
    Texture* background;
    KeyboardClient& kbd;
};

class TitleGameState : public GameState
{
public:
    TitleGameState(SDL_Renderer* renderer, KeyboardClient& kbd)
        :
        kbd(kbd)
    {
        background = new Texture("blue.png", renderer);
    }
    ~TitleGameState() {}
    void HandleEvents()
    {
        while (!kbd.KeyEmpty())
        {
            KeyEvent e = kbd.ReadKey();
            switch (e.GetCode())
            {
            case SDLK_RETURN:
                if (e.IsPress())
                {
                    printf("OK");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    void Logic() {}
    void Draw(Graphics&gfx)
    {
        background->Draw(0, 0, gfx);
    }

private:
    Texture* background;
    KeyboardClient& kbd;
};
```

I define the class right afterwards, and I know I can just move it above IntroGameState, however when I implement the menu game state, it will go back and forth between the menu state and the overworld state.  How can I get around this?

Compiler Error:

> ```
> error C2514: 'TitleGameState' : class has no constructors
> File: gamestates.h
> Line: 28
> ```

Line 28 is this line of code:

```
currentState = new TitleGameState(renderer, kbd);
```

Comment: Please provide 1)exact error message with the line number 2)the relevant piece of code where the error appears 3)decide on the problem you'd like us to address: a)compile error or b)going back and forth.

Comment: Edited it with the full code for those classes and the compiler error.

Comment: Do you know how the compiler processes your code from top to bottom?

Comment: I do, but wasn't thinking of that. Now I remember why I usually split my code into a header file and a cpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error on the line `currentState = new TitleGameState(renderer, kbd);` is because the compiler has yet to see the constructor for the class. It doesn't know how to compile this code.

If you forward declare the class `class TitleGameState;` all you can declare is pretty much a pointer `TitleGameState*`.

To compile the code you have, you need to define the class before using. Note: defining the class does not mean defining all the methods as well. A class definition consists of the method and member declarations.

```
class TitleGameState : public GameState
{
public:
  TitleGameState(SDL_Renderer*, KeyboardClient&);
  ~TitleGameState();
  void HandleEvents();
  // ...
};

class IntroGameState : public GameState
{
  // ...
}
```

After the definition of the classes, you can then define the member functions;

```
/*inline*/ void TitleGameState::HandleEvents()
// inline is needed if the method is defined in a header file
// to help avoid linker errors
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: So, split it into a header file and a cpp file? I was trying to avoid all that but if it's what I have to do...lol

Comment: You don't have to split them between the files if you don't wish to. But the code would need to be constructed as if it where split. If the method definitions are in the header files, add `inline` to avoid linker errors

Comment: I was going to split it later, but since it's i'm just testing the code right now, i was trying to avoid it. I find that splitting code makes it easier to read and follow.

Comment: You could then look to only split off the minimum required for the compile to run, so migrate code out of the class definition only as required. You can freely mix method definitions inside and outside the class.